# Standards for System Tray applications

Tags: language-agnostic, system-tray

Are there any standards out there for how applications that have a system tray icon should behave?

I recently wrote an application that sits in the system tray most of it's life. I handed it to a friend, and her first instinct was to double click the icon to get at the main window (which worked). But this got me thinking. In .NET atleast, there are all sorts of different events and ways of attaching things to your system tray icon (click [left/right], double click [left/right], context menus, off the top of my head). Just thinking about it, I've come up with applications with a right click context menu (most), left click brings up the same context menu (Live Messenger), a (different) left click context menu (Daemon Tools), left click opens the main window (alot of the Windows notifications), left double click opens the main window (mIRC, lots of other applications). I've yet to discover an application that uses right double click, though I'm sure it's possible...

Are there any usability guidelines or standards as to how your application should behave under any of these particular situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to read [Those notification icons, with their clicks, double-clicks, right-clicks... what's up with that?](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/04/30/9577283.aspx) from Raymond Chen's blog [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/).

He even includes a link to [Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448%28loband%29.aspx#guidelines) for the Notification Area (more commonly known as the "[system tray](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/10/54831.aspx)").

Comment: '*Of course, Raymond Chen points out that we're not meant to call it the system tray, but when Google gets almost three orders of magnitude more hits for “system tray” than for “taskbar notification area” I think the battle is lost.' -- Jonathan Hardwick (http://blogs.msdn.com/jonathanh/archive/2004/12/19/327145.aspx). Also, it's usually called the system tray on non-Windows systems, further confusing the matter...

Comment: @Matthew: The ship has certainly sailed on that issue, which is why I didn't post 'incorrectly called the "system tray"'. I have edited my answer further to now say 'more commonly known as the "system tray"'.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's hard to have a standard when every one is different.

*Double* click to open and right click to have some sort of context menu are the ways I expect it to behave. Having an Exit command as the bottom icon on the context menu is good whenever it makes sense as well.

Comment: Much to everyone's dismay it's entirely possible to have a standard which everyone ignores :(

Comment: These suggestions sound similar to those outlined in the Notification Area Guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448%28loband%29.aspx#interaction

Comment: yeah, there is this software that I use called PlayOn media server.  it has this problem where clicking doesnt work as you expect.